# The status of "Editor assigned" did not change for 4 weeks

Tags: publications

I submitted the manuscript to a Springer medical journal. One month later, major revision was suggested. Then I re-submitted the revised form. One day later, the status changed as "editor assigned". Finally, this status did not change for 4 weeks. What does it mean? Has the assessment started yet? 
Thanks..

Comment: This might be a duplicate, but why the down votes?

Comment: I am in the same situation, the status of my revised manuscript after minor revision is "Editor Assigned" for more than 2 months. I would like to know what happened in your case? Appreciate for your kind response in case.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, "editor assigned" means that the paper has no not been yet sent to the review. Once is sent to review you usually have "under review". When the paper was reviewed at the first round, did you have "under review" status?

Comment: Sorry, at first review, there was  "under review" status. But now I dont have.

Comment: Then it is  most likely still with the editor. Probably, the editor is on vacation.  The editors are active researchers, so they can be busy. You can either patiently wait or you can write a gentle Email to the journal asking about the status of your paper. But be very polite: " My paper was submitted  after  revision on ???. I would like to know what is the status of it." It's better to send such Email not to the editor, but to some journal technical stuff. They will check this for you.